# Polymer 2.0 not able to get child from id

Tags: polymer, parent-child, polymer-2.x

I'm kind of new to Polymer and i'm having an issue lately. I create dynamically a certain amount of instances of a web-component of mine, and I'd like to be able to call a method on these instances from my parent-component but I can't figure out how to do it even with answers I found online.

Here's my parent method where I try to call the children method (the e.detail.id match the id of the specific instance of my children I'm trying to reach) :

```
childObj: function(e) {
     var name = "selectObj"+e.detail.id;
     this.$.name.hello();
},
```

And my child basic method :

```
hello: function() {
     console.log("hello");
}
```

The ID that name gets exists well but still i get this error

```
TypeError: Polymer.dom(...).querySelector(...) is null
```

I also tried replacing `this.$.name.hello()` by `this.$$('#selectObj'+e.detail.id)` but still I get the same error.

Here's how I create my childrens elements :

```
newObj: function() {
            var dynamicSelect = document.createElement("pbd-object-select");
            dynamicSelect.num = this.nbObj;
            var newId = "selectObj" + this.nbObj;
            dynamicSelect.id = newId;  
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#listeObjet").appendChild(dynamicSelect);
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with they way you are trying to query for that element. One of them is that by doing this:

```
this.$.name.hello();
```

You are basically looking for an element with the id "name", not one with the id equal to what you have in the variable `name`. Something like:

```
this.$[name].hello();
```

might work better in general, but it would still have some problems in your particular case. `this.$` is just a "shortcut" to get elements by ID in an easy manner, **but**, it's just an object in which references to the elements that exist and have ids when the element is connected. Because of that it doesn't work with elements that are conditionally included (in `dom-if`s for example), or that are dynamically generated, like in your case.

You can just use the `getElementById` method, like you would do in vanilla JS, just keeping in mind that you are querying in your element and not in `document`. So it would be something like:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById("selectObj"+e.detail.id).hello()
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer it helped me understand the problem of the shadowDom.
But I still have the same error even with your correction, the only difference is that I have one element created in my html and all the others are created dynamically. And on the element created in the html the hello function is well called, but for the others i still get the error   "TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementById(...) is null". I edited my first comment to show how my childrens are created dynamically if it is anyhow related.

Comment: @ligmagma well, what I wrote there are the basics.. for more details you have to debug, see if the IDs are correct, if the ones computed are.. for example, for me, without knowing the rest of your code and what `this. nbObj` is it kind of sounds like you are generating the same ID every time, so it's normal that just the first one is found..

Comment: well i just formated my code not to past every single line, but the IDs that I'm trying to reach are well existing but I still can't access it and I can't figure out why

Comment: @ligmagma there isn't much I can say with the details you pasted here.. just try to debug it step by step.. I don't know, for example, how the event that is supposed to be caught by `childObj` is dispatched and listened for.. are you sure that you get the id in it's detail object?

Comment: Actually in the end it work with this.$$('#id').hello(), from what I found the this.$$ function allows you to find element in the shadow dom unlike the this.$ one. What is weird is that I had already tried this and it didn't worked but in the end my problem is solved so still happy. Thank you for your answers that helped me understand the shadow dom problem better !